# Android - Efficiently update counters in views

Tags: android, performance, view

In the app I'm writing I have a bunch of stats which I want to display for the user.

The stats include when a specific module was last run, when it will be run next, when the last communication with the server was made and then the next one is going to be.

As well as this there are stuff like memory usage (simple memory usage, not measuring the actual usage).

The memory usage etc can be updated every few seconds so that not a problem the but the times needs to be updated every second at least (for counters).
Since running every second (or even with 500ms period) results in irregular updates/skipped seconds I now run it at 300ms period.

I did notice however that my app began to lag when starting.
After some profiling it turns out it's the views that need to resize that is taking 70% of the time and the string formatter (for formatting the counter) takes pretty much the rest.

Apart from the CPU being used I see a lot of allocations, every few seconds I see a GC_CONCURRENT in the logcat.

Any tips on solving this efficiently?

Comment: Stupid question : Are you using a separate thread for calculations?

Comment: No, don't think it'd matter if I did since most of the time is spend on re-sizing views which can only be done from the main UI thread.

Comment: You should not be doing any processor intensive work on the UI thread.

Comment: I am aware of that and the calculations are not heavy, it's updated the views that is and as I said that has to be done on the UI thread.

Comment: Ah sorry looks like I got confused :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by writing my own timer that sleeps in short increments and only updates the view when a full second has passed.

This way the fire interval will be `[period, period+sleepTime)` which is acceptable when you choose a short sleepTime.

I've also changed so it says "5 minutes ago" and I have two timers, one that fires every minute and one that fires every second.

Answer (score 0):

Can you restructure it in a way so that the fiews require less resizing? Eg: set the width of your element to fill_screen or a DP size that is bigger than the longest string size

Comment: I'm using tableviews with max width on that column, I don't think it would matter anyway.